# MS OAuth aunthentication - work account only

Tags: oauth, microsoft-teams

For my app I'am using the OAuth authentication. I know user's email, so I'm passing the `login_hint` param to the authorize endpoint:  `https://login.microsoftonline.com/TID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?login_hint=XXX@domain.com`. There is a chance user has both accounts `personal` and `work` for the email, like this:

[image] 
Is there any parameter or way how to "setup" the endpoint to offer the `work` account only? I don't want to allow the user log in with the personal account.

Answer (score 1):

Users can have multiple "work" accounts too, and "work" is relative to a specific Azure AD/Office 365 tenant. You may have a work email address for a user whose company does not use Azure AD or Google GSuite, and while it's a "work" email address, that won't work either.

In the general case, there is no way to tell what a "work" email is; the real question is, is it a valid account inside an Azure AD/Office 365 tenant? And the only way to know that for certain is to have them log into that tenant (the `TID` in the URL); if it works, then it is a valid account. If not, it isn't a valid account. The `login_hint` will actually help with that because it will try a "silent login" that will log the user in without having to re-enter their credentials (kind of like SSO but it's not really SSO; the login dialog will briefly pop up). If the user isn't already logged in on that device to that tenant, they will see the login experience. I think that's what you want.